# Why does the firebase authorization error appear?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, redux-firestore

I don't understand why I have this error:

```
auth.js:204 POST https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=AIzaSyApbrATkWmIfa0wkxIC9105e4K46ytzI4g 400
```

This happens when, for example, I enter the correct email and the wrong password when I log in, or when I register a new user with an email that is already in use.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

import { IUser } from '../models/user'
import { authTypes } from '../store/reducers/authReducer'

export function signIn(
  credentials: IUser
): (dispatch: Function, getState: object) => void {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: object) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(credentials.email, credentials.password)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        dispatch({ type: authTypes.LOGIN })
      })
      .catch((err): any => {
        dispatch({ type: authTypes.LOGIN_ERR, payload: err.message })
      })
  }
}

export function signUp(
  newUser: IUser
): (
  dispatch: Function,
  getState: object,
  { getFirestore }: { getFirestore: any }
) => void {
  return (
    dispatch: Function,
    getState: object,
    { getFirestore }: { getFirestore: any }
  ) => {
    const firestore = getFirestore()

    firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
      .then(res => {
        return firestore.collection('users').doc(res?.user?.uid).set({
          firstName: newUser.firstName,
          lastName: newUser.lastName,
        })
      }).catch((err): any => {
      dispatch({ type: authTypes.SIN_UP_ERR, payload: err.message })
    })
  }
}

export function signOut(): (dispatch: Function, getState: object) => void {
  return (dispatch: Function, getState: object) => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
        console.log()
      })
  }
}
```

And here are the rules set on my firebase:
[image: firebase rules]

Also for an example I give a part of the Login component:

```
const Login = () => {
  const auth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.firebase.auth)
  const authP = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth.authErrorLogin)

  const history = useHistory()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const { handleSubmit, handleChange, state, errors } = useForm(
    submit,
    validateFormRegister2
  )

  function submit() {
    dispatch(signIn(state as IUser))
    history.push('/')
  }
***
```

PLS HELP...
[image: The error about the wrong password is caught, but also in the console the error which is specified in this post is entered.]

Comment: it sounds like you are asking why firebase is returning an error when a user enters an incorrect password or trying to create a user with an already used email - which all sounds exactly like how it should work to me. Or am I missing the question?

Comment: I intercept errors (see specified code), but this error is still displayed.

Comment: it looks like when you get an error from firebase you are dispatching it to Redux (or some other reducer) and I imagine your Login component renders errors from that reducer, but you don't have any of that code shared.